# H2O cluster show status charmap error

Tags: h2o, colorama

When trying to print out the cluster show status of a H2O cluster on Windows computers, it gives the following error:

> h2o.init(nthreads = -1, strict_version_check = False)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 267, in init
>       h2oconn.cluster.show_status()
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\cluster.py", line 237, in show_status
>
> ["Python version:",            "%d.%d.%d %s" % tuple(sys.version_info[:4])],
>     File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\h2o\display.py", line 49, in **init**
>       self.pprint()
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\h2o\display.py", line 59, in pprint
>       print(r)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 40, in write
>       self.__convertor.write(text)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 141, in write self.write_and_convert(text)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 169, in write_and_convert
>       self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 174, in write_plain_text
>       self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp857.py", line 12, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2021' in position 210: character maps to 
>   H2O session _sid_a367 closed.

It seems that colorama Python library can not handle different locale/charsets outputs on Windows terminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for this problem is to SET below environment variable before running the Python script:

> set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8